# Inviting friends to play a game in a facebook app

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have a multiplayer game for the facebook platform and I would like to give users the ability to invite their friends to play a game. I know how to let user invite their friends to add my application but what I don't know is how to let users ask friends to join a game. Note that this happens after the friend has added my application. Is there an API to do this real time communication in FB? Or should I install my own chat mechanism? I don't want to write something if its already there.

Thanks for any information. It would really save me a lot of trouble.

- Pav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have two friends **A** & **B** who have *added* your application and actively *interacting* with it (in-game) and you want **A** to be able to invite (in terms of multiplayer games not Facebook) **B** to join the match or party?

If this is your question then NO, you can't!
As long as both friends have authenticated your App and in-game (you should be able to capture who's online and the relation between the online users, friends or not, easily I suppose), it's up to you (App) to handle the communication between the online users.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will handle it through my own server I guess.